# how to find whether we are in root path or not in rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, root

I developed a application using Rails 2.3.8 and In there root path I need to show particular table in one separate div and on other pages I need to remove that details so I need to check whether it in root path or not. So how can I find it on view file ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with apneadiving's answer, however if you wanted to you can do this:

```
request.env['PATH_INFO'].eql?('/')
```

or:

```
params[:controller].eql?('root_controller') and params[:action].eql?('root_action')
```

better:

```
#some_helpers.rb

def check_root
  params[:controller].eql?('root_controller') and params[:action].eql?('root_action')

#view

if check_root
  #your table code
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use a real architecture.

In your layout:

```
<%= yield :root_content %>
```

In your root view

```
<% content_for :root_content do %>
  Your html goes here
<% end %>
```

In other views, don't use this container.

This way your code is clean and maintainable.

Comment: Hay thanks for your reply can you please explain the meaning of "root_content" ? Is it inbuilt method ?

Comment: No, you can name it the way you want. You an even create as many as you want. You should really adopt this instead of conditionnal...